# Codeigniter, preventing browser's back button after form submit

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a Controller in Codeigniter like following :

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Charity extends MY_Controller {
    public function index()
    {
        if($this->input->method() === 'post'){
            $data['name'] =  $this->input->post('name');
            $this->load->view('review_page', $data); 
        }else{
            $this->load->view('charity');
        }
    }
}
```

the views are :

```
charity.php 
<form method="post" action="/">
<input name="name" type="text"/>
<input value="send" type="submit"/>
</form>

review_page.php
<h1><?= echo $name; ?></h1>
```

When I submit the form I get the review_page view loaded but if I click on the browser's back button I come back to the form. Is there a why to make the form page expired after it is submitted so that the back button does not show it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Back button does not work because you never actually redirect to a different URL. You need to build your code so that it redirects.
I would build another method that loads the review page like so

```
public function index() {
    $this->load->view('charity');
} 

public function reviews(){
  if($this->input->method() === 'post'){
      $data['name'] =  $this->input->post('name');
      $this->load->view('review_page', $data); 
  } else {
      redirect('charity');
  }
}
```

And your html

```
<form method="post" action="reviews">
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help:

at the top of charity.php add this code:

```
 <?php
   session_start();
   if ( isset($_SESSION['isSubmit']) and $_SESSION['isSubmit'] == 'ok' )
   {
     echo 'page is expired: form already submit !';
     session_destroy();
   }
 ?>
```

at the top of review_page.php add this code:

```
 <?php
   session_start();
   $_SESSION['isSubmit'] = 'ok' ;
 ?>
```